# In QML, the Loader freezes the UI when loading large/time-consuming objects

Tags: qt, qml

There are several questions on this subject that are unrelated to my question and They did not produce any results for me.

Imagine I have a splash screen with [AnimatedImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html) in QML that I want to display when my **heavy components** are loading in the background, so I use a [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-loader.html) to load assets in background, but when the loader starts loading my UI freezes(i.e. that AnimatedImage), I can see that BusyIndicator not freezes.

I have provided the full source code in the [github repository](https://github.com/robosina/SplashScreenIssue.git) so that you may test it more easily.

my questions are:

1. Do Loaders really run in the background (for example, if I'm trying to connect to a server in my constructor, can Loader handle this situation or do I have to run it in another thread)?
2. How should such scenarios be handled so that I do not see any glitches?

### window.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    id:mainWindow
    y:100
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    //splash screen
    Popup {
        id: popup
        width: mainWindow.width
        height: mainWindow.height
        modal: false
        visible: true

        Overlay.modeless: Rectangle {
            color: "#00000000"
        }

        //Splash loader
        Loader{
            id: splash
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "qrc:/Splashscreen.qml"
        }
    }
    
    // Timer that will start the loading heavyObjects
    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 2000
        repeat: false
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            loader.source = "qrc:/heavyObjects.qml"
            loader.active = true
        }
    }

    //write a loader to load main.qml
    Loader {
        id: loader
        anchors.fill: parent
        asynchronous: true
        active: false
        //when loader is ready, hide the splashscreen
        onLoaded: {
            popup.visible = false
        }

        visible: status == Loader.Ready
    }
}
```

### SplashScreen.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: splashRect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "white"
        border.width: 0
        border.color: "black"

        AnimatedImage {
            id: splash
            source: "qrc:/images/Rotating_earth_(large).gif"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

### heavyObject.qml

```
import QtQuick

Item {
    function cumsum() {
        for(var j=0;j<100;j++){
            var p = 0
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                p *= i
            }
        }
        return ""
    }

    // show dummy text that this is the main windows
    Text {
        text: "Main Window" + String(cumsum())
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most things you do in QML are handled in the QML engine thread. If you do something heavy in that thread, it will block everything else. I haven't checked your source code, but, in terms of heavy initialization, we can break it up with Qt.callLater() or similar so that the QML engine thread can catch up on UI/UX events.

For example, in the following:

- I changed `cumsum` from a function to a property
- I introduced `calcStep` for do a calculation for one `j` iteration
- I use `Qt.callLater` to instantiate the next iteration
- I kick off the calculation during `Component.onCompleted`

```
    property string cumsum
    function calcStep(j) {
        if (j >= 100) {
            cumsum = new Date();
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
             p *= i
        }
        Qt.callLater(calcStep, j+1);
    }
    Component.onCompleted: calcStep(0)
}
```

If your initialization is more sophisticated, you may want to give Promises a try. This allows you to write asynchronous routines in a synchronous type of way, e.g.

```
    property string cumsum
    function calc() {
        _asyncToGenerator(function*() {
            for(var j=0;j<100;j++){
                var p = 0
                status = "j: " + j;
                yield pass();
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                    p *= i
                }
            }
            cumsum = new Date();
        })();
    }
    function pass() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            Qt.callLater(resolve);
        } );
    }
    Component.onCompleted: calc()
```

In the above, the `cumsum` calculation has been using a derivative of the async/await pattern. For this, to work I make use of `_asyncToGenerator` provided by a transpiler on babeljs.io. This is required since the QML/JS does not support async/await pattern until Qt6.6.

The `pass()` function operates similarly to Python pass but has my implementation of `Qt.callLater` wrapped in a Promise. Invoking it with `yield pass();` does nothing but allows your function to momentarily release control so that the UI/UX events can catch up.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    property string cumsum
    property string status

    // show dummy text that this is the main windows
    Text {
        text: "Main Window: " + cumsum
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Text {
        text: status
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: parent.height * 3 / 4
    }

    function calc() {
        _asyncToGenerator(function*() {
            for(var j=0;j<100;j++){
                var p = 0
                status = "j: " + j;
                yield pass();
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                    p *= i
                }
            }
            cumsum = new Date();
        })();
    }

    function pass() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            Qt.callLater(resolve);
        } );
    }

    function _asyncToGenerator(fn) {
        return function() {
            var self = this,
            args = arguments
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                var gen = fn.apply(self, args)
                function _next(value) {
                    _asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "next", value)
                }
                function _throw(err) {
                    _asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, "throw", err)
                }
                _next(undefined)
            })
        }
    }

    function _asyncGeneratorStep(gen, resolve, reject, _next, _throw, key, arg) {
        try {
            var info = gen[key](arg)
            var value = info.value
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error)
            return
        }
        if (info.done) {
            resolve(value)
        } else {
            Promise.resolve(value).then(_next, _throw)
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: calc()
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

If you are interested in some of the work I've done with async and QML Promises refer to the following GitHub projects:

- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-promises
- https://github.com/stephenquan/qt5-qml-promises-demo

Comment: Though this is not what I had in mind, your suggestions are thoughtful and greatly appreciated. I am working with an MCU that is not very resourceful. As I have tested, my splash screen freezes when I load a large image, and I would like to fix this issue. It is possible to think of that dummy for loop as a mimicking of that large image, I don't like to see this freeze in my splash screen, do you have any idea for that? Thanks

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi okay, I had a look at your GitHub repo. The animating gif is small and is not the cause of the problem. The only reason why the animating freeze is the heavyObject.qml is also running in the same QML Engine thread hence why it blocks the UI. It is as I mentioned before. You need to give us some indication of what heavyObject.qml does so that we can see if there are ways we can get it to back off from the QML engine thread. If not, then UI/UX things, such as mouse clicks, animating GIFs, etc, will be blocked.

Comment: The information you provided is something that is difficult to obtain in such a structured manner, so thank you for the kind assistance and the time that you dedicated.